# DIV does not float to right with float:right

Tags: html, css, z-index, openlayers-3

I am using OpenLayers 3 to make a interactive game map. I want to have *side panels* on the right and left side, both of them have *two containers* on the inside, but the map must be able to go *under* those containers. Makes it more visually pleasing as it goes into the margin of the two containers. I used *z-index* for that.

I have `float: left;`on the left sidepanel, and `float:right;` on the right sidepanel but they seem to make no diffrence.
I included *LEFT* and *RIGHT* in the titles on the top container so I know if they are floating propertly. **They aren't since there is nothing on the right and the right side is above the left side.**

**HTML**

```
          <div id="map" class="map"><!--Map DIV, contains all of the webpage content-->

                <!--Left SideBar-->
                <div class="sidebar-left">
                    <div class="container-top">
                        <h3>Miscreated interactive map LEFT</h3>
                        <p>You can use this map to find your location and navigate through the wasteland of Miscreated.
                            Also you can make your own waypoints on the map and <b>share them with friends</b>! </p>
                        <h4>Sign in for markers &middot <a href="#">Make new Group?</a> </h4>
                        <form>
                            <input type="text" name="groupname" placeholder="Group name" class="glowing-border" style="height: 20px; width: 48%;">
                            <input type="text" name="secret" placeholder="Secret" class="glowing-border" style="height: 20px; width: 48%;">
                        </form>
                    </div>

                    <div class="container-bottom">
                    map version: 0.1 <i>game version: .40</i>
                        <h3>Interactive Map Development</h3>
                        <h3>Upcoming changes to interactive map</h3>
                        <ul>
                            <li>User placed markers/waypoints</li>
                            <li>Login/Clan system</li>
                            <li>More resposive design</li>
                        </ul>
                        <p>I spend a lot of time developing this map, any feedback or suggestions for the development of this project are more then welcome. <a href="" target="about_blank"><b>Visit discussion on forums</b></a></p>
                    </div>  
                </div>

                <!--Right SideBar-->
                <div class="sidebar-right">
                    <div class="container-top">
                        <h3>Miscreated interactive map RIGHT</h3>
                        <p>You can use this map to find your location and navigate through the wasteland of Miscreated.
                            Also you can make your own waypoints on the map and <b>share them with friends</b>! </p>
                        <h4>Sign in for markers &middot <a href="#">Make new Group?</a> </h4>
                        <form>
                            <input type="text" name="groupname" placeholder="Group name" class="glowing-border" style="height: 20px; width: 48%;">
                            <input type="text" name="secret" placeholder="Secret" class="glowing-border" style="height: 20px; width: 48%;">
                        </form>
                    </div>

                    <div class="container-bottom">
                    map version: 0.1 <i>game version: .40</i>
                        <h3>Interactive Map Development</h3>
                        <h3>Upcoming changes to interactive map</h3>
                        <ul>
                            <li>User placed markers/waypoints</li>
                            <li>Login/Clan system</li>
                            <li>More resposive design</li>
                        </ul>
                        <p>I spend a lot of time developing this map, any feedback or suggestions for the development of this project are more then welcome. <a href="" target="about_blank"><b>Visit discussion on forums</b></a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.map {
    position: relative;

    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;

    min-height: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.sidebar-left {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    float: left;

    width: 25%;
}

.sidebar-right {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3;
    float: right;

    float:right;
    width: 25%;
}

.container-top {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;

    padding: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
    margin: 2% 2% 2% 2%;

    outline: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border-color: #9ecaed;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #9ecaed;
}

.container-bottom {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;

    padding: 1% 1% 1% 1%;
    margin: 5% 2% 2% 2%;

    outline: none;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    border-color: #9ecaed;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px #9ecaed;
}
```

Comment: You can't float an element and position it absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

Alright this is getting weird, but I have solved my own problem again. Instead of using a float, I am using the left property, since I know that my sidebar is 25% wide I just need to move it 75% left.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `clear: both;` property. However, if you setup a jsfiddle for this I can have a further look. This would probably be a better solution than using absolute positioning. However, if absolute is the way for you then that is fine, but I would try to use the clear property as stated above.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but I have already managed to solve it the way I stated and I don't feel like spending more time on a diffrent solution.